# Spreadsheet: ADRESS() works in ARRAYFORMULA(), wrapping it in INDIRECT() doesn't?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

For **Google Spreadsheet**,

I'm using this formula in column B to try and acquire specific cells over the columns B to Z:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISODD(COLUMN(B:Z)),ADDRESS(ROW(),(COLUMN(B:Z)-2),1,TRUE),ADDRESS(ROW(),(COLUMN(B:Z)-1),1,TRUE)))
```

This Output is correct:

```
A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I       J
CellA7  $A$7    $A$7    $C$7    $C$7    $E$7    $E$7    $G$7    $G$7    $I$7
```

But when i try to use these strings to get the values in each one with INDIRECT:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISODD(COLUMN(B:Z)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),(COLUMN(B:Z)-2),1,TRUE)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),(COLUMN(B:Z)-1),1,TRUE))))
```

it seems to go wrong somewhere, and the result is now:

```
B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I       J
CellA7  #VALUE! CellA7  #VALUE! CellA7  #VALUE! CellA7  #VALUE! CellA7
```

Where the `#VALUE!` error message in column C,E,G,I is:

```
Error
Function ADDRESS parameter 2 value is 0. Valid values are between 1 and 18278 inclusive.
```

Comment: What does your input or ideally layout look like?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach My plan is to have a date in CellA7 to du my personal budget calculations and i want it to automatically fix the dates as headlines that i can use in other calculations, like this:

`2015-08-25   2015-09-24   2015-09-25   2015-10-24   2015-10-25   2015-11-24` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISODD(COLUMN(B:Z)),EDATE($A7,FLOOR(COLUMN(B:Z)/2)),EDATE($A$7,FLOOR(COLUMN(B:Z)/2))-1))
```